# wget not resolving relative links properly?

Tags: wget

Back to basics. I have a static web where the links are typically relative.

All works fine in browsers and in Google Crawler, but `wget --spider` resolve relative links against the site root.

That is, in a page at `/foo/bar.html`, a link `<a href="test.html">` is resolved as `/test.html`, instead of `/foo/test.html`.

My question is: **Did I forget/overlook something basic in how HTML links work, or is `wget --spider` resolving the URIs wrong?**

The HTML specification says that if there is no `base` element, then the current document is the base.

There's [this wget issue](http://savannah.gnu.org/bugs/?50173) but it should be fixed in my version.

```
$ wget --version
GNU Wget 1.19.4 built on linux-gnu.

-cares +digest -gpgme +https +ipv6 +iri +large-file -metalink +nls 
+ntlm +opie +psl +ssl/openssl
```

My command is:

```
wget --spider --convert-links -r -p --level 1 -E --user-agent=crawlerTest http://www.zizka.ch/
```

Answer (score 0):

I generally use these switches when I want to spider a site using `wget`:

```
$ wget -r -l4 –spider -D unix.stackexchange.com https://unix.stackexchange.com/
```

This tells `wget` to recursively (`-r`) spider (`-spider`) up to 4 levels deep (`-l4`). The `-D` switch tells `wget` to only follow links which fall in this domain.

Running this will look like this:

```
$ timeout 1 wget -r -l4 –spider -D unix.stackexchange.com https://unix.stackexchange.com/
--2018-07-31 20:28:40--  http://xn--spider-vg0c/
Resolving xn--spider-vg0c (xn--spider-vg0c)... failed: nodename nor servname provided, or not known.
wget: unable to resolve host address ‘xn--spider-vg0c’
--2018-07-31 20:28:40--  https://unix.stackexchange.com/
Resolving unix.stackexchange.com (unix.stackexchange.com)... 151.101.65.69, 151.101.193.69, 151.101.129.69, ...
Connecting to unix.stackexchange.com (unix.stackexchange.com)|151.101.65.69|:443... connected.
HTTP request sent, awaiting response... 200 OK
Length: 106032 (104K) [text/html]
Saving to: ‘unix.stackexchange.com/index.html’

unix.stackexchange.com/index.html               100%[====================================================================================================>] 103.55K  --.-KB/s    in 0.1s

2018-07-31 20:28:40 (1.02 MB/s) - ‘unix.stackexchange.com/index.html’ saved [106032/106032]

Loading robots.txt; please ignore errors.
--2018-07-31 20:28:40--  https://unix.stackexchange.com/robots.txt
Reusing existing connection to unix.stackexchange.com:443.
HTTP request sent, awaiting response... 200 OK
Length: 2148 (2.1K) [text/plain]
Saving to: ‘unix.stackexchange.com/robots.txt’

unix.stackexchange.com/robots.txt               100%[====================================================================================================>]   2.10K  --.-KB/s    in 0s

2018-07-31 20:28:40 (228 MB/s) - ‘unix.stackexchange.com/robots.txt’ saved [2148/2148]
```

Comment: That's nice, but does any of that affect relative links?

Comment: I'm not able to replicate your issue locally. Can you point to a specific spot where you're seeing an issue?